# android 2.x - 4.3.x phonegap doesn't support flexbox css3

Tags: javascript, android, css, flexbox

I am developing and app with phonegap. I wanted to use the flexbox in my playfield, but i have this issue:

Chrome, Mozilla, android 4.4 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aunA.jpg

android - 2.x - 4.3.x - https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqIf0.jpg

```
  playfield {
  width: 408px;
  height: 408px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -o-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -o-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: space-around;
  -moz-box-pack: space-around;
  -ms-flex-pack: space-around;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

playitem {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  border-collapse: 
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
  -o-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
  -moz-flex-grow: 0;
  -o-flex-grow: 0;
  -ms-flex-grow: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

Please, help me to fix this issue ;(

Comment: Don't use flexbox. http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Support modern native mobile browsers

You can use the modern flexbox syntax on most native mobile browsers today meaning it will work in phonegap view as well.

### Older native mobile browsers

On Android 4.1, 4.3, Safari 5.1 You can use [old flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/) and in IE10 the [2012 syntax](http://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/).

### Automagic solution

If you want to automatically set the prefixes and old/2012 syntax automatically you can use [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#flexbox-filters-etc).

If you use [grunt](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#grunt) or [gulp](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#gulp) you can automagically add prefixes to your workflow.